# Kernel panic - not syncing: Waiting TID List traversal - Adaptec SCSI card 29320ALP - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel

First: I am a Linux newbie. Don't hurt me :-) !

Configuration: Old bios (2003), ATA bus for harddisk. Adaptec SCSI 29320ALP card in PCI slot, default settings. SCSI cable with terminator at one end: End without terminator connected to Adaptec card, end with terminator connected to an magnetic/optical removeable drive. The Adaptec SCSI BIOS sees the drive correctly as devive #0, the card itself is address #7.

When installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / 32 bit on the computer, the installation stopped front up and dropped to the text monitor with Kernel Panic (as in title) and could not continue.

I removed the SCSI cable from the Adaptec (I kept the Adaptec in the computer), and now Ubuntu could be installed.

After installation, I re-attached the SCSI cable to the Adaptec. Now, Ubuntu again dropped to the text monitor with Kernel Panic (as in title) and could not continue.

Suggestions?

Comment: what is your current kernel? `uname -a`

Comment: Its the kernel from the 12.04 LTS 32 bit download. How can I find the details?

Comment: run `uname -a` in terminal.

Comment: Got it: 3.8.0-29-generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest trying an install with 13.10 as it has a newer kernel release.

If the problem still persists then you could try to  [(update to the most current kernel)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade) retest and [(submit a bug report)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) if it doesn't already exist.

EDIT:

More details here: [What is kernel panic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic)

Could be a missing module?

Driver/Module info: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/aac.4freebsd.html

Comment: I will try that. Strange, though: This SCSI card is dated 2003 so I assumed that the Linux kernel would have knowledge of it...

Comment: Could be corrupt installation media. Maybe retry with a fresh download and disc?

Comment: Hmm.The rest of the system seems OK. Still, I will try 13.10, and then let you know. That will bring in another inst. media.

Comment: OK, I installed 13.10 and it survived (no kernel panic) :-). So I guess that I'll work with this version. So now I only have to understand how to mount a SCSI device into the system, but that is another thread.

Comment: `mkdir /mnt/super_tester` and `mount /dev/sdaXXX /mnt/super_tester` and `umount /dev/sdaXXX` and `rm -r /mnt/super_tester`