# Ubuntu 12.04 LTE update caused a kernel panic errors

Tags: 12.04, server

3 days ago I've updated Ubuntu 12.04 LTE on our server (mainly to get new OpenSSL libs), rebooted, everything was fine. Then after 6 hours server stopped to respond. I rebooted again and it was works for 12 hours. Then it halted.

This morning after another reboot I've found "bad_area_nosemaphore" and "do_page_fault" messages on the screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Again the server stopped to respond, but after reboot it started without errors.

What can cause such a problems and how to fix them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is kernel panic?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic)

Comment: Could be a hardware problem. Have tried to investigate in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

Distribution Updates often cause problems, I had errors most times Upgrading.

The best way is to backup your data and make a clean install.

Should work out fine. :)

Comment: I disagree. I have some machines in my household and some have been upgrade from 6.06 to 14.04 and while there **can** be problems while upgrading the resulting system shouldn't be buggy or unstable. Kernel panics are definitely not to be expected.

Comment: Ok, but still reinstalling will help

Comment: Not if there is a hardware problem.

Comment: If it's no hardware problem...