# Kernel Panic - Ubuntu 14.04 crashes when playing call of duty

Tags: kernel, games, crash

After playing Call of Duty 2 for about 5-10 minutes my computer crashes (with an Kernel Panic) and displays this message:

[image: Error screen]

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A so called [kernel panic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic) happened (you can see this on the last lines of output). This can have a range of reasons, but you describe that it happens after having used the computer intensively for some minutes, therefore I suspect that gaming causes your computer to heat up, leading to this.