# Kernal panic-ubuntu linux 20.04.3

Tags: kernel

I have faced kernel panic -Not syncing fatal exception in interrupt
what does it mean?
how to find out from command line?
what is the cause of this issue?
Note: I don't have upgrade OS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is kernel panic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic)