# Why am I unable to to create an Ubuntu VM?

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded the ubuntu iso and oracle VM as suggested in training videos, twice.

where the VM installation stops/fails/ceases to install:

[image]

I have followed the instructions in your tutorial, yet ubuntu fails to install.  If anyone can assist me with resolving this issue, I would be extremely appreciative.

snippit of iso and Virtual Box Application:
[image]

Comment: Did you check the ISO as being downloaded correctly as per [instructions](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) as an invalid ISO can cause what you show (*why the validation steps exist*), or did you apply sufficient resources to run the VM (Oracle state virtualbox can *misbehave* if insufficient resources are given and this they report as a user error).  Your question is vague on specific details; and why not provide release details in your question, details of your setup etc, and what validation you actually performed (*if any*)

Comment: The installation fails because of [kernel panic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic). There may be various reasons. Maybe, the downloaded Ubuntu file got corrupt during download. Maybe, some you set some settings in the Virtual Box incorrectly. Maybe a cat walked over your keyboard. These are some of the reasons why.

Comment: It is unclear what "training videos" and "your tutorial" refers to (this could be resolved by the provision of links), but you should know that the contributors here are volunteers, and are unlikely to have created "your tutorial".